# Распознание цифр с картинок при помощи тесеракт Python

Tags: python, tesseract

Час добрый
Скорее всего подобные вопросы появлялись много раз, но решение для себя так и не нашел
Подскажите пожалуйста как при помощи тесеракта можно обработать следующее изображение:
[image: Картинка на входе]

Чтобы вытащить цифру 0. Изображение уже обработал, но получение с него цифры не выходит, пытался получить её следующим методом:

```
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r'screens\tmp_mask_text_enemy.png'), lang='eng')
```